# area integration under bijective differentiable mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-integration

I was reading Lars Ahlfors Complex Analysis and encountered this statement from the author (p.75,76).

Let $E$ be a point set in the plane whose area
$A(E) = \int\int\limits_{E} dx dy$ can be evaluated as a double integral.

If $f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$ is a bijective differentiable mapping, then by the rule for changing integration variables the area of image $E' = f(E)$ is given by:

$A(E') =\int\int\limits_{E} |u_xv_y - u_yv_x|dxdy$.

$u_x,u_y,v_y,v_x$ are the partial derivatives.

I could not understand how the formula for $A(E')$ is derived. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the use of the Jacobian for this purpose in the real setting?

Comment: $A(E')=\int_{f(E)} 1 =\int_E |u_xv_y-u_yv_x| $ since the Jacobian of the transformation is $|u_xv_y-u_yv_x|$

Comment: Not really. Can you point me to a resource about this?